# Deployed contract address in Truffle does not match Ganache

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I have truffle set up with Ganache. I am running tests on my solidity contract that involve sending ether to the contract and withdrawing it from the contract. Funny thing is my tests are PASSING, but when I look, none of the transactions are going to or coming from the actual address of my deployed contract as shown in Ganache.

The ACCOUNTS in Ganache are having their balances deducted or added to as one would expect, but when looking at the transactions, the contract the tests are interacting with is an address that doesn’t seem to exist. For example, on one deployment the contract address in Ganache was: 0x683EB77121Ab6A40cAE6BD78001E5eD95dbC8872 but the mystery contract address was: 0xe0107F0a6210A7200636F3D15Ee0a3741Fe815F6

Any idea how to resolve this?

Here is the code of my test file:

```
const CoinFlip = artifacts.require("CoinFlip");
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');

contract("CoinFlip", async function(accounts) {

  it("should make sure the bet is not less than 0.1 ether", async function(){
    let instance = await CoinFlip.deployed();
    await truffleAssert.fails(instance.bet(0, {from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("1000000000000000", "wei")}),
    truffleAssert.ErrorType.REVERT);
  });

  it("should make sure the bet is not more than 10 ether", async function(){
    let instance = await CoinFlip.deployed();
    await truffleAssert.fails(instance.bet(0, {from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("11", "ether")}),
    truffleAssert.ErrorType.REVERT);
  });

  it("should reject a bet if not enough in contract to cover it", async function(){
    let instance = await CoinFlip.deployed();
    await truffleAssert.fails(instance.bet(0, {from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether")}),
    truffleAssert.ErrorType.REVERT);
  });

  it("should accept a bet if there is enough in contract to cover it", async function(){
    let instance = await CoinFlip.deployed();
    console.log(instance.address);
    console.log(CoinFlip.address);
    await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: instance.address, value: web3.utils.toWei("15", "ether")});
    await truffleAssert.passes(instance.bet(0, {from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether")}),
    truffleAssert.ErrorType.REVERT);
  });


});
```

Comment: Please explain how exactly you are deducing all of this information (which is most likely where the problem is).

Comment: I thought I already answered this above. But let me just take the current deployment for example: 
- Result of Truffle migrate shows the address for my CoinFlip contract is: 0x0fF211B1A628412afF0299B672620642e9A5dD8B
- In Ganache, it also shows the address for that contract to be 0x0fF211B1A628412afF0299B672620642e9A5dD8B
- when I click on the Transactions tab in ganache, and view the transactions executed by my tests, each of the transactions are showing a 'to contract address' as: 0x16f9f503005f23C96cf1676f0A9302f9b8453484

There is no contract in ganache showing with this address

Comment: Just print all the relevant addresses in your Truffle test.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking me to do exactly. But in the console when I type 'truffle networks' it outputs: Network: ganache (id: 5777)
  CoinFlip: 0x0fF211B1A628412afF0299B672620642e9A5dD8B
  Migrations: 0xC0a6067FD293B443d47BCD6181de537d50Fc26a1

There are no specific contract addresses hardcoded in my tests. I am using lines such as: await web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: instance.address, value: web3.utils.toWei("15", "ether")}); 
    await truffleAssert.passes(instance.bet(0, {from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("2", "ether")}),

Comment: In your Truffle test (the JS code), add something like `console.log(myContract.address);`, etc.

Comment: OK, done. It prints out the mystery address, which makes sense since that is the contract it is somehow interacting with.

Comment: I just edited the post above to include my testing code

Comment: Does this have something do with truffle's clean room environment setup feature?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if I restart everything and run it from scratch the issue shows up the first time I run the file.

Comment: According to the Truffle documentation: "Before each `contract()` function is run, your contracts are redeployed to the running Ethereum client so the tests within it run with a clean contract state.". More info: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript

Comment: That's fine, but then the contract address in my Eth client (Ganache) should update its deployed address. Again, truffle and ganache are seemingly in agreement on what the contract address is, based on console output and the contract page on ganache - yet the transactions are going to another address.

Comment: OK, some more info… this is not an issue with only this project. I just went back and tried with another project that we did on my solidity course. The exact same issue is there. The transactions are going to a different address than the stated contract address in truffle and ganache. I just didn’t notice it before.

So this issue is a deeper on between truffle and ganache - not about my project.

Can anyone else confirm on any project of theirs whether the contract shown on individual transactions in ganache is the same as the contract address shown on the contract tab in ganache?

Answer (score 1):

Official Documentation on the same:

[How Contract function during test run behaves](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#use-contract-instead-of-describe-)

So here is the thing....

In order to test, you dont even have compile/migrate it to the local ganache server.

Let say you have a fresh workspace in Ganache... and you run

```
truffle test
```

It will compile the contracts and put it into a temp directory "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\test--19324-4OOYkxXEiDUd" in windows system. So here is your compiled artifact i.e. contract.json file is, no build/contract/*.json is created till now.

Then it will run those transactions which you are testing in your test, and those transactions will be recorded in ganche... as below:

[image: Transaction List]

Now if you go to Contracts tab, which is populated based on truffle-config.js... its empty i.e. no contract has been deployed yet. and that is evident from build/contracts folder too.

[image: Contract List]

So I my best guess is....

Separate Contracts are deployed at the beginning of truffle test command.

Comment: No this is not correct, at least in my case. I DO have contract deployed and showing in Ganache before the tests are run, because I went ahead and linked truffle-config.js to Ganache. And that is the point of my question - why does Ganache show my contract deployed with an address that is different than the one truffle has and is working with.

Comment: Thats the whole point of my analysis... I wanted to check even if we dont deploy, are we able to run our test? And conlusion is yes, we can run our test without deploying the contract. Which tells that while running test command  separate deployment of contracts happen, Which is different than on already deployed in local network.

Because of that everytime you run test, you see different contract addresses...

Comment: OK, but how does this help resolve the ganache address problem?

Comment: What I feel its not a problem but a behavior/feature of truffle.
Dealing with contract deployment while running test.

Comment: It IS a problem. The whole point of Ganache is to provide a block explorer-type UI for interacting with the blockchain during development. As such, one SHOULD be able to click on a contract and see the transactions. Also, one should not see transactions to non-deployed contracts in the block explorer. It is a disconnect that should not be.

Comment: Still I dont see it as a problem reason being.... Let say u dont add the truffle-config.js in ur ganache workspace. Do u see those contracts in that space? No. Ganache is able to show that contact because it picks those addresses from build/contracts artifacts. To verify this, take ur mystery address and update the current contract address in artifact i.e. json file. And relaunch ur workspace it will start showing u that deployed contract address.

Comment: There is one more reasoning for this is that... If u want ur tests to run independent and in fresh contract that wont be possible if truffle uses an alredy deployed contract. Because it might have states updated. Which will result into inconsistent test outputs. Hence deploying new contracts with each test command becomes necessary. And genache is not able to show them because build artifacts doesnt track all the test and its addresses... Also there is no use of that too.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to get help with fixing my stated issue, rather than spending time being convinced my issue doesn't matter.

Comment: So fresh contracts are must have requirement for tests. Since a user can run test n number of times there is no point of tracking all those short lived deployed contracts...... Hence I dont see thats as a problem that ganache is not showing those address.

Comment: @user10221 lets hope ganache team provide us with some kind of flags where we can enable or disable all contract addresses deployed to network.... Which will also show those contracts which are part of different projects.